# Quelle séquence d'onomatopée(s) reproduit le mieux le battement du coeur ?

Tags: oral, littérature, santé-et-médecine, onomatopées, son

Quelle (séquence [d'](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k123239j/f2.item.texteImage)) [ononmatopée](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4415)([s](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatop%C3%A9e)) ou de syllabe(s) représente(nt) le plus couramment/littérairement/fidèlement le battement du [coeur humain](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C5%93ur), avec combien de répétitions et quelle ponctuation en composition, et pourquoi ; peut-on illustrer ; est-ce très uniforme dans la littérature ?

Comment: Charles Trenet répondrait "Boum boum" ... à ma connaissance il n'y a pas de règle, ceci n'est donc pas uniforme et chacun pourrait venir avec sa propre onomatopée

Comment: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_d%27onomatop%C3%A9es_dans_diff%C3%A9rentes_langues#Battements_de_c%C5%93ur) donne "boum boum" et "bam bam" pour le français. Mais je pense que c'est plus pour mettre quelque chose que pour consigner une règle établie.

Comment: "boum boum" me semble le plus naturel, en tout cas, çà ne choquerait personne de l'entendre dans ce contexte.